# Keyboard Navigation Between Expendable Panels

Tags: sapui5

We have a number of expanded Panels with a list of items in each. Is it possible to navigate just to the first entry in the expandable panel without using the mouse?

You can tab from the last record in the panel current to the first record of the next, but is it possible to **jump to the next panel** if you aren't on the last record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by using the F6 key. On a view containing something like:

```xml
<Panel>
    <Input />
    <Input />
    <Input />
    <Input />
</Panel>
<Panel>
    <Input />
    <Input />
    <Input />
    <Input />
</Panel>
```

Having the focus in the very first Input and then pressing F6 will cause the focus to the first input from the second panel. You can find a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/zcp4x5vj/.

For reference, the full reference for moving with the keyboard in UI5 can be found on the [official documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/6b741a6133284bd78e897cef8b75f6d9). This is the relevant paragraph:

> <kbd>F6</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> skips focus of UI elements (forward / backward)  UI elements within an application can be grouped together (for example, all elements in the header of an application). You can skip focusing the elements within a group by using these keys.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!